# Binding fails when using DataTemplate in DataGrid

Tags: uwp, datagrid

I've got a uwp application that uses a DataGrid.

Most of the columns in my DataGrid are fairly ordinary text columns which work fine.

In one column I have a button that changes both its text and its color to match the data in the cell. To accomplish this, I used a DataTemplate with an embedded Button, and various properties of the Button are bound to the data using converters.

When I run the app, the first screenful of data looks correct, and as I scroll down the data also looks fine, but when I scroll back up to the top, the state of this button is wrong for many of the rows. (But the other, ordinary data for those rows is correct).

I checked using the debugger to make sure that the underlying data hadn't changed, and it had not.

I also used the debugger to see when my converters were being called, and they aren't being called as often as I'd expect. Initially there is one call for each row, but when I scroll up after scrolling down, I only see the functions being called occasionally, if at all.

I'm not sure what I did wrong. As far as I can tell all of my bindings are correct and they work fine initially, they just aren't being used to update the screen when the content scrolls. What else can I try to fix this?

Here is the XML:

```
<controls:DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="markCompleteCol" Header="Complete" Tag="Complete">
     <controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
             <Button x:Name="markCompleteColButton" Background="Transparent" Visibility="{Binding Path=IsCompleted, 
            Converter={StaticResource inverseBoolToVisConverter}, ConverterParameter=false}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Click="MarkCompleteColButton_ClickAsync">
                <Button.Content>
                  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                       <Border CornerRadius="14" 
                               Background="{Binding Path=IsCompleted, Mode=OneWay, 
                               Converter={StaticResource markCompleteButtonBackgroundColorFormatter}}" 
                               BorderBrush="{Binding Path=IsCompleted, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource markCompleteButtonOutlineColorFormatter}}"
                                BorderThickness="0">
                         <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=IsCompleted, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource markCompleteButtonFormatter}}" 
                                               Margin="16, 5, 16, 5"
                                               TextAlignment="Center"
                                               Foreground="{Binding Path=IsCompleted, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource markCompleteButtonOutlineColorFormatter}}"/>
                            </Border>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Button.Content>
            </Button>
        </DataTemplate>
    </controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</controls:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Frank

Comment: Please share your xaml code or provide us [mcve].

Comment: From what I've been reading, I think disabling row virtualization would solve my problem, but there does not appear to be a way to do that in a UWP application. The specific properties don't exist.

Comment: Have you implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface for the data model?

Comment: Yes, I do implement INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: I check your code, it looks correct, I could not repro the issue with above, could you create blank app and provide to us?

Comment: What's important to understand here is that I am not changing the value of the property for any rows. I am just scrolling the list.

Comment: Hi @user92238 , If you want to test under non-virtualized conditions, consider putting the `DataGrid` in the `ScrollViewer`, which will invalidate the internal virtualization of the DataGrid, but at the same time bring performance problems with data loading.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Embedding within the ScrollViewer fixed the problem, and didn't really cause any notable performance issue.